# check_and_cast(): Cannot cast 'inet::physicallayer::INoise*' to type 'const inet::physicallayer::NarrowbandNoiseBase *'

Tags: wifi, omnet++, ini, inet

I am following the inet documentation to set up a simulation and use Ieee80211RadioMedium and Ieee80211Radio, but I am getting the following error:

> check_and_cast (): Cannot cast 'inet :: physicallayer :: INoise *' to type 'const inet :: physicallayer: : NarrowbandNoiseBase * '- in module (inet :: physicallayer :: Ieee80211Radio) AODVNetwork.host [0] .wlan [0] .radio (id = 53), during network initialization

I am using the following parameter settings:

```
*.radioMedium.typename = "Ieee80211RadioMedium"

*.radioMedium.backgroundNoise.power = -90dBm
*.radioMedium.mediumLimitCache.centerFrequency = 2.4GHz
*.radioMedium.mediumLimitCache.minReceptionPower = -85dBm
*.radioMedium.mediumLimitCache.minInterferencePower = -110dBm
*.wlan[*].radio.typename = "Ieee80211Radio"

**.wlan[*].mac.dcf.channelAccess.cwMin = 7
**.wlan[*].radio.bandwidth = 2MHz
**.wlan[*].radio.centerFrequency = 2.412GHz
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.bandwidth = 2MHz
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.power = 20mW
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.headerLength = 192b
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.centerFrequency = 2.412GHz
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.bitrate = 11Mbs
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.preambleDuration = 10us
**.wlan[*].radio.receiver.sensitivity = -85dBm
**.wlan[*].radio.receiver.snirThreshold = 4dB
**.wlan[*].radio.receiver.bandwidth = 22MHz
**.wlan[*].radio.receiver.energyDetection = -85dBm
**.wlan[*].radio.receiver.snirThreshold = 4dB
**.wlan[*].radio.bandName = "2.4 GHz"

**.opMode = "a"
**.bandName = "2.4 GHz"
```

1. [List item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOSWI.png)

Please help

Comment: Why does your question include a list item?

Comment: @Boric why you comment does not include an answer